# DataTables: Display abbreviated number, but sort by the original number

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a table with 20+ columns of relatively large numbers. I'd like to abbreviate the numbers, for instance, 204555 might be abbreviated as 204K, and 4735853271 might be abbreviated as 4.7B, and so forth. I have PHP code that does the conversions for me.

But I can't figure out how to display the abbreviated number in the table, but allow DataTables to sort by the original number?

I've done something like this before using basic javascript, and simply encoded the actual number using something like: 4.7B

Is it possible to do something similar with DataTables? and if so what is the simplest way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add a column with the unformatted data and set it up so that when you sort the formatted data it actually uses the unformatted column as the basis for the sort. It is possible to hide the unformatted  column.

[Example of Datatables iDataSort](http://datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort)

[Example of hidding columns in datatables](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html)